# unable to run chef-client from workstration

Tags: chef-infra

I have a windows workstation and a node on AMAZON EC2. I was able to bootstrap amazon node. Now I want to run `chef-client` on my workstration. `chef-client` was throwing "Private Key Not Found"  error.

```
C:\chef-repo>chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.0
[2014-01-09T15:24:52-06:00] WARN: unable to detect ip6address
Creating a new client identity for XXXXXX.ent.ad.xxxx.com using the validator key.
[2014-01-09T15:25:03-06:00] WARN: Failed to read the private key C:\chef\validation.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or director
y - C:\chef\validation.pem>

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "XXXXXX.ent.ad.xxxx.com"
================================================================================

Private Key Not Found:
----------------------
Your private key could not be loaded. If the key file exists, ensure that it is
readable by chef-client.

Relevant Config Settings:
-------------------------
validation_key "C:\chef\validation.pem"

[2014-01-09T15:25:03-06:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2014-01-09T15:25:03-06:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read C:\chef\validation.pem, which you told me to
 use to sign requests!
```

I copied `validation.pem` from ec2 amazon node to `c:\chef` to resolve the error. Now it throws the following error

```
C:\chef-repo>chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.0
[2014-01-09T15:28:39-06:00] WARN: unable to detect ip6address
Creating a new client identity for XXXXX.ent.ad.xxxx.com using the validator key.

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "XXXXXX.ent.ad.xxxx.com"
================================================================================

Network Error:
--------------
There was a network error connecting to the Chef Server:
Error connecting to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/satishtest/clients - A connection attempt failed because the connected p
arty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respon
d. - connect(2)


If your chef_server_url is correct, your network could be down.

[2014-01-09T15:29:15-06:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connecti
on failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2)
```

I am able to run `knife client list` or `node list` which proves that there is no issue with network from my workstation. Any help appreciated

Comment: But if you can run `knife client list`, then you already have a client certificate and don't need to register anymore (that's what you need the `validation.pem` for).
Check your `.chef/knife.rb` (in your repo), to where the setting `client_key` points. There should be your client certificate. If no such setting exists. Create a new client for you in the Chef admin interface and place the certificate e.g. in `.chef/client.pem` and point `client_key` to that file.

Comment: I can't run chef-client from workstation. It throws "private key not found" error as mentioned in the above post without copying validation.pem. Knife.rb client_key is pointing to a file is repo directory

Comment: What do you mean with "Knife.rb client_key is pointing to a file is repo directory"? Ah.. I guess you mix up some things.. so `knife` works, but `chef-client` doesn't on your workstation. I would say that's fine, except you want to provision your workstation. If you want to do so, you have to point `/etc/chef/client.rb` to the private key, too.

Comment: Have you tried following the debugging instructions here: https://learnchef.opscode.com/errors-and-problems/401-unauthorized/?

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page. I wanted use my workstation as a node. I don't have access to start SSH service on my workstation(windows). So bootstrap won't work. I created client.rb and added https_proxy,chef_server_url,validation_key values. I validation_key was pointing to orgnization-validator.pem. With these settings I have made some progress. I don't get "network error". Now it is attempting create client but fails with 401 error. I have tried with new org validator with no luck.

Comment: If you don't have access to start SSH on your workstation, you probably don't have access to do most of the things you would normally do using chef-client ...

Comment: bootstrap can also be done over winrm... https://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_windows.html#bootstrap-windows-winrm

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the tags states: Questions should pertain to the Ruby portions of coding. General DevOps questions may be asked on https://devops.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This method is applicable only if both Workstation and node are Windows machines. Install Winrm on both of the machines. And try running following command.

> knife winrm name:NodeName "chef-client" -x ServerUsername -P "password" -a ipaddress

eg.

> knife winrm name:node1 "chef-client" -x administrator -P "pass@123" -a ipaddress

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had this same issue today while running this on an ubuntu machine. The same thing worked on another centos node.

The problem my user didn't had proper access in running chef-client on the nodes.

Once i logged in with root user everything was working smoothly.

:)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

**option 1.** probably there were some fatal issues and leftover packages files that forcing us to bootstrap again the instance and attach it to chef server.

In order to fix that issue remove client and node from chef server, remove chef packages from node and bootstrap again.

```
# remove client/node from chef-server using knife
cd <chef-workstation-directory>
knife node delete <node-name>
knife client delete <node-name>

# connect into machine and remove chef packages and dependicies
ssh -i /home/administrator/.ssh/admin_key admin@<instance-ip>
sudo apt autoremove chef
exit

# bootstrap machine again with the right role/policies through the terminal
cd <chef-workstation-directory>
knife bootstrap <instance-ip> --bootstrap-version 12 -N <node-name> \
--ssh-user administrator --ssh-identity-file /home/administrator/.ssh/admin_key \
--sudo -r 'role[dev]' -E 'dev'
```

**Option 2.** Alternatively, this issue can related to a bad file permission of ssh key or inaccurate public/private key, you can validate that by just connect to this instance using ssh and ensure you can access this server.